# DIV after div is hidden and will not show in block or inline

Tags: jquery, html, css

Strange title but I can explain and show a demo:
I have a drop down menu UL LI it is working fine, but after the menu I have a div to give it some space on left column navigation div so it looks nice and after the space I will have more content.
The problem is that the second div (spacer after first div menu) hiddes behind the top div and will not show.

here is the code

```
<div class="menu">
<ul>
<li>
<a href="#"><span class="normal icono-menu"></span>Menu</a>
<ul class="submenu">
<li><a href="#link"><span class="normal icon-link"></span>Link One</a></li>
<li><a href="#link"><span class="normal icon-link"></span>Link Two</a></li>
</ul></li>
</ul></div>

<div class="separate"></div>

//More content comming here
```

As you can see DIV menu is a drop down menu then comes the separation div and then more content.

I tried position relative absolute and other stuff nothing working.
I am new to CSS3 I used tables before.....

DEMO fiddle here
https://jsfiddle.net/761khuLx/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give your `.separate` `<div>` a `clear:both;` CSS rule then it should show up.

That’s because you’ve got some `float:left;`s in your Menu.

Comment: If I delete the float left will it work too? I really dont need the float left

Comment: Sure, if you don’t need it, if it doesn’t break anything.

Comment: Tested without float left and it looks really uggly

Comment: @novato I think only `.menu li a` needs `float:left;` like here: https://jsfiddle.net/761khuLx/2/

Comment: Yeah you are correct. Just a small question about the same: are the attributes Diaplay block and position relative ok and necessary in this css? I just added and added code like crazy to test it and make it work but it would be fine to see how to do it correct. Thanks for your help and time

Answer (score 0):

If you want your `div.seperate` to show, add `clear:both` to it's css;

```
.seperate{
clear: both;
}
```